# Linq Query Syntax and Complex Where Conditions

Tags: linq-to-objects

I want to use a Linq to Objects query to select certain members from a list based on fairly complex selection criteria (for simplification represented here as `return true` :-)

Using the Where extension method, this works just fine:

```
    var matches = (from wm in Members
                   select wm).Where(p =>
                   {
                       return true;
                   });
```

However, when I attempt to do the same thing using the query syntax:

```
    var matches2 = (from wm in Members
                    where (p =>
                    {
                        return true;
                    })
                   select wm);
```

The compiler objects

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not
>   a delegate type

What is going on here behind the scenes, and how can I use a lamda expression with the query syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query gets translated to something like:

```
Members.Where(member=> p=>{return true;});
```

...which doesn't compile because (warning: technical errors probably be here) `Where()` expects a parameter of type `Func<TSource, bool>`. You are giving it a parameter that would get converted to type `Func<TSource, Func<???, bool>>`. The error is telling you that a lambda expression cannot be converted to a bool, because lambda expressions can only be converted to delegate types (e.g. `Func<...>`, and bool is not a delegate type.(/end bumbling explanation)

In query syntax, whatever you put in your `where` clause goes after the `=>` in the lambda expression for the generated `Where()` method call. Note that your first snippet can be rewritten as:

```
Members.Where(p=>true);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
from m in members 
where true 
select m;
```

if you really need a lambda with a statement block in it you can do:

```
var lam = (Member m)=> {return true;};
from m in members
where lam(m)
select m;
```

or to inline it:

```
from m in members
where ((Func<Member, bool>)(Member m)=> {return true;})(m)
select m;
```

or you can use a regular method instead of an anonymous one:

```
public bool DoStuff(int i)
{
    return true;
}

...

from m in members
where DoStuff(m)
select m;
```